# Race condition on INSERT statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sybase

So I have a process to load data into a table. Prior to this, as per the targets instructions (can't be changed), an audit record is placed in a table like this:

`INSERT INTO audit VALUES (SELECT (MAX(batch_id) + 1), "feedname" from audit)`.

Now 10 parallel processes for loading are kicked off, all with a different feedname. The connections are via Java and they are all running the statement with auto commit ON.

However, they are colliding with each other due to the batch_id primary key constraint.

What is wrong with my statement?

Answer (score 0):

With a multi-threaded environment, 2 threads can see the same value of batch_id because the select statement occurs before the insert.
For example, imagine this processing happening in order:

```
Thread 1: 
SELECT (MAX(batch_id) + 1) # returns 1
Thread 2:
SELECT (MAX(batch_id) + 1) # returns 1 again, nothing has changed
Thread 1:
INSERT INTO audit VALUES (1, "feedname"); # because 1 was SELECTed before 
Thread 2:
INSERT INTO audit VALUES (1, "feedname"); #crash!
```

If your database supports it, use a sequence, or an auto-increment primary key.

EDIT: work-around in response to OP's comment

1.Intialise process by getting the next batch_id value into a Java variable using the SQL statement:

```
 SELECT (MAX(batch_id) + 1) from audit;
```

2.Use a synchronized Java method to get the next ID:

```
 private synchronized int getNextBatchId() {
   return nextId++;
 }
```

3.Use the method in Prepared Statements:

```
 PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO audit VALUES (?, 'feedname')");
 ps.setInt(1, getNextBatchId());
 ps.execute();
```

Comment: Given that I cannot alter the DDL of the target environment, is there any other workaround?

Comment: @Ben Use locks or semaphores to ensure that the select and insert calls are atomic.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, these aren't threads...they are completely separate processes kicked off by windows scheduler. I would still like them to run in parallel...I was hoping there was something I could change in the query in order to get this to work to save having to do IPC. Will try using a lock.